# Remove the morebutton TabbarItem from UItabbarcontroller

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I have a tabbar controller which includes six tab bar item. But the problem lies in the more button appears and the whole view get distract due to it. So how do i set all the six controller in the tab bar controller. I dont want to use any customized class.

If i creating a view manually in xib file. Then the tabbar is allowed having six item. Please see the attached images

[image]

In above image you can see a favourite tab bar controller which is created manually in xib, so if that is valid. Then how can i create like six tabbaritem in the uitabbarcontroller defined in app delegate. Please reply me back and dont give suggestion for using external classes or customize class.

Answer (score 2):

Five is the most it will display. The standard icons won't fit otherwise. From the documentation:

> The tab bar has limited space for displaying your custom items. If you add six or more custom view controllers to a tab bar controller, the tab bar controller displays only the first four items plus the standard More item on the tab bar. Tapping the More item brings up a standard interface for selecting the remaining items.

More than five will show in interface builder because it has no other way of showing you which items are linked to the controller.

So, at risk of a downvote, you'll have to use a custom container that can show more than five options.

Comment: could you guide me to a custom controller which is easier to implement and which works smoothly

Comment: Sorry, I've never needed one. I'd try on cocoacontrols.com